# Determine if Javascript select 'change' event performed by user versus via code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a way to determine if a select element's `change` event was performed by user versus via code (dom manipulation)?

I have a timer that auto sets some select values based on some condition and then formats the select color to signify "success" (green select box).

Because I have the form set to fire off an ajax request when the select change event is fired, it does this for both the timer-based changes to the selects, as well as user-based select changes.

I'd like to only fire that ajax event when it's a user-based select change.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

When I output the value of `e.isTrusted`, it says Undefined in the log.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log(e.isTrusted); // This outputs "Undefined"

            if (e.isTrusted) {
                save_review();
                console.log("Point status changed by user - Saved");
            } else {
                console.log("Point status changed programmatically - Not Saved");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm using select2.

Comment: `I have a timer that auto sets some select values based on some condition … because I have the form set to fire off an ajax request when the select change event is fired` so the user can't perform setting the same select values that the timer can do? And if the user can, why does the user-initiated change require an ajax request but the timer-based not?

Comment: Both user and timer can set all the same selects (and user can override the timer-based setting of the select value). The selects are "statuses" for a given list of alarm points. Some are "auto updated" (with the timer), and some the user specifies the status (manual selection).

Comment: jQuery creates a wrapper around the native events. And `isTrusted` is a native property, which is not listed as exported properties. So you would need to use `e.originalEvent.isTrusted`, but you might need to check first if `e.originalEvent` exists.

Comment: And what part of the timer is triggering the `change` even. How does that part look like? To me, it seems a bit as if you try to use a hacky approach to solve a problem that should be solved in a different way.

Comment: $("#pt" + value + " option:nth-child(2)").attr('selected', true).trigger('change');

Comment: How is it hacky? In some instances, code handles the selection, and in some instances, the user handles it. I was trying to figure out how to determine which one performed the action (and did in the answer below).

Comment: It reads at least a bit fishy and as if it is some kind of design flaw. It is a bit like abusing exceptions for control flow. Normally there shouldn't be the need to differentiate between an event triggered by the user and one by code because both should have the same logical intent.  I looked a bit through the reason why you do it and it is because **select2** requires the `change` event to be triggered to sync the HTML representation of **select2**  with the native `select` element ([Add, select, or clear items](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)).

Comment: Personally, I would consider that as a design flaw of **select2** because the HTML standard differentiates between programmatically changing states that don't trigger events, what you actually do, and user-initiated changes that trigger an event. But the method **select2** suggest contradicts this. Now your code inherits this design flaw, but it looks like there is no way around that.

Comment: I would suggest to add something like `The time-based change event is fired with: $("#pt" + value + " option:nth-child(2)").attr('selected', true).trigger('change');  which is required to synchronize the state of of the `select` element with the **select2** representation` as this might help others having the same problem. I thought of adding that edit myself, but that might change the meaning of the question, in case you do also some other actions based on the programmatically based event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this based on a solution I found googling and with the help of the community-provided answers above.

When the timer-based event triggers, I now pass it a boolean value (auto_selected):

```
$("#pt" + value + " option:nth-child(2)").attr('selected', true).trigger('change', [true]);
```

In my event listener, I am then able to check against the value of that parameter:

```
        $(document).on('change', 'select', function (e, auto_selected) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log("Auto-selected: " + auto_selected);

            if (typeof auto_selected == 'undefined' || !auto_selected) {
                save_review();
                console.log("Point status changed by user - Saved");
            } else {
                console.log("Point status changed programmatically - Not Saved");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This isn't logical though. What if it's auto-changed but the user would agree with this change and wants it saved? They can't select it because it's already selected, wouldn't trigger a change. (they'd have to go back and forth with some other option to get it saved, not intuitive at all) - I think you should rethink the UX here.

Comment: True. bit of an edge case in my specific use-case, and it would auto-select on page reload or refresh anyway, so not a "loss of data" because it didn't save. Adding: If the user were to change the actual value of the select after the timer-based selection, it WOULD still save. So if user wanted to keep the timer-based value, but didn't save, the selections wouldn't be lost on page reload as they would be auto-reselected again based on the same criteria prior.

Comment: I would argue it can feel like a loss of data though, because if the user sees the correct value and doesn't remember if they set it themselves or it was set automatically, they could expect it as set and saved and would then perceive it as data loss when it changes on reload. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: By the way, the `typeof auto_selected == 'undefined' ||` part is unnecessary because `undefined` is falsy anyway.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback! I think because the auto-selections would never change between page loads (same condition would always be met when they visit the page), there'd be no threat of the values changing between visits. Only when they've overridden it, which it WOULD save, would there be a deviation, but then it wouldn't matter because it would have been user-defined already and timer-based setting would not undo that.

Comment: Noted on the "undefined" thing. Was thinking it was like "catching" an exception and was the "righter" way of doing it. Will remove!

Comment: The `typeof` shenanigans are only for the case where you don't even know if the variable exists at all or not, which is hardly ever required, except in some edge cases when you are writing libraries (but even then there are often better solutions nowadays). In this case you know it's defined because you define it a few lines above as argument. (it doesn't matter if the argument is actually passed to your function or not.) - if you'd like a default value, you can define it in the argument list as follows: `(e, auto_selected = false)`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Wrinkle gained!

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) on the event object that you can use to check whether the event is triggered by user action or by script.

> that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via EventTarget.dispatchEvent()

```
if (e.isTrusted) {
  /* The event is trusted */
} else {
  /* The event is not trusted */
}
```

if you use jQuery, it's inside `event.originalEvent`

```
if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
  /* The event is trusted */
} else {
  /* The event is not trusted */
}
```

If you use `select2`, listen to the event `select2:select`, and check for `event.params.originalEvent.originalEvent` (two `originalEvent` here, seems like a bad implementation inside the library itself)

```
$('#your-selector').on('select2:select', function(e) {
   if(e?.params?.originalEvent?.originalEvent) {
     // user action

   } else {
     // programatically trigger
   }

});
```

Comment: Updated main question with my code snippet. When I output the value of e.isTrusted, I get "undefined".

Comment: updated my answer as well

Comment: That is also coming back as undefined. Tried wrapping it in $(e) as well, same output.

Comment: You need to define `e` in the event definition ... `.on("change", function(e) { ...`

Comment: updated my answer again, seems like a library issue

Comment: When using Select2 library, I found i didnt need the IF/ELSE statement inside your function, just using '$('#your-selector').on('select2:select', function(e) {}' and perofming an action inside those brackets seemed to work for me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I looked a bit through the documentation of `select2` because I was not really happy with the initial solution in my answer. And they actually provide a solution for that using a namespaced events.

[Limiting the scope of the change event](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event):

> It's common for other components to be listening to the `change` event, or for custom event handlers to be attached that may have side effects. To limit the scope to **only** notify Select2 of the change, use the `.select2` event namespace

I'm wondering why they don't suggest that one as default in the documentation. I still think that their suggested way (using the not namespace verion) to sync the native `select` element with the HTML representation of **select2** is odd. Because why should the default behavior of programmatically changing an input element trigger a `change` event.

So if you use `$("select option:nth-child(2)").attr('selected', true).trigger('change.select2');` it won't trigger the `change` event.

```js
$('select').select2();


function commonTaskOnChange() {
   console.log('commonTask')
}

$(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
   console.log('selection changed by user')
   
   // in case you want to perform some common task for timer and change event
   commonTaskOnChange();
})

setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('timer will change selection')

   // trigger the namespaced change event
   $("select option:nth-child(2)").attr('selected', true).trigger('change.select2');

   // you could still perform some action that the change event has in common by calling a function here
   commonTaskOnChange();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```